# is there a way to fix an improperly formatted to: header in postfix?

Tags: postfix

I have a program that connects to postfix to send email. Unfortunately, there is a bug with this program that causes it to send improperly formatted To: headers when used with multiple addresses. The improper To: looks like this

```
<name@domain.com,name2@domain.com,>
```

instead of

```
<name@domain.com>,<name2@domain.com>
```

I came up with this replacement rule (along with one to replace the trailing comma)

```
/([^>]),([^<])/ REPLACE $(1)>,<$(2)
```

to fix it. But it's not satisfactory because it will apply to all commas that aren't surrounded with angle brackets in the headers. Not to mention that I believe that REPLACE will only execute the replacement once.

Is there a way to to fix this without passing the request through a proxy script to fix the improperly formatted addresses? The program that is outputting this invalid data is closed source and the maker of it has so far refused to help.